# default back button does not appear in uinavigation control

Tags: iphone

I am working on uinavigation based application. When ever I add a view controller to my project and navigate to it using pussviewcontroler, I dont get default back button on the navigation control. This is happening first time to me, whenever I am creating an application I am not getting default back button
Thanks for viewing my question

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually that happens when the previous UIViewController has no `title` or a zero-length `title`.  Strangely, the back button still exists (try touching the screen where you expect it to be), but isn't drawn.

Comment: got it when I gave the title to the page, thanks. can I change the text of this back button? Previous page title is too long.

Comment: I suppose you can change the title when pushing the new view controller and set it back in `viewDidAppear`.